For RoCE LAG, How to remap all QPs from one port to another?
My Linux environment using RoCE LAG bonding device (802.3ad)for fail over. Without splitting the bond device, is there any methods to migrate all QPs on one port to another? I tried "ifconfig down" one port but traffics can still be seen on two ports. I also tried "ifdow n" one port, but it destroyed RoCE LAG bond device, this is not acceptable for me.
